# Removing a substring between track number and title

Tags: bash, sed, music, rename, awk

I need help with a little bit of bash trickery.  In organizing my music collection I've come across a set of tracks which are named in the format

```
%track%. %artist% - %title%.%extension%
```

How can I use sed, awk, grep, or any other third-party tool to get this in the format of

```
%track%. %title%.%extension%
```

Comment: You probably want the `rename` command, using something like `rename 's/\. .* - /. /' FileMask`, but there will be problems if `'. '` or `' - '` appear in any of the track, title or artist fields, which is not unlikely. You should invoke with the `-n` option first to see the effect before running the full command.

Comment: A couple of real examples would be a bit more useful. Do any of the placeholders contain spaces or dots?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out why this wasn't working - what I thought were hyphens weren't actually hyphens, they were some weird Unicode character than looks nearly exactly like a hyphen!  So my script wasn't picking up on it.  Ultimately the script I wrote the first time around works like a charm:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for f in *.mp3
do
        if [[ $i -lt 10 ]] ; then
                name="0$((i++)). "
        else
                name="$((i++)). "
        fi
        name="$name$(echo "$f" | sed 's/^[^—]* — //')"
        mv --verbose "$f" "$name"
done
```

Just leaving this here for future reference of anyone looking for this particular format.

Comment: I have learned that copy and pasting from GUI applications like Firefox into a terminal can convert MS Word-style em-dashes into what looks like hyphens. Actually though, it's some weird character that throws errors. This happens to me when I'm pasting shell snippets from MS Word into a terminal and a cp -f flag gets the dash converted automatically into a em-dash unless you undo it.